# Окрасить в пепельный цвет. Одним словом.

Tags: словообразование

Возможно ли использование слова: "испепелить" или "опепелить" в значении "окрасить цветом пепла"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, тут не подобрать какого-то одного слова для обозначения этого действия. Предложенные Вами варианты в речи не употребляются, а если говорить о сером цвете, то и вовсе неприлично выходит)))
Так что, остается только вариант "окрасить в пепельный цвет"

Answer (score 2):

Нет, без пояснения такое использование невозможно.
Вообще по такой модели образуются только "очернить", "обелить" и "озеленить" - но у них переносное значение стало основным. Ни для одного, даже самого простого цвета (красный, синий, желтый...) в прямом значении таких глаголов не получаются. Так что не стоит даже и искать чего-то подобного для такого редкого случая как "пепельный". Пользуйтесь аналитической конструкцией. Наподобие той, что предлагает **Fuchoin Kazuki**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ИСПЕПЕЛИ́ТЬ, -лю, -лишь; -лённый (-ён, -ена); совер., кого (что) (высок.). Обратить в пепел, сжечь дотла. 
Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете воспользоваться этим словом и для требуемого значения?

Comment: Разве это я предлагала? См формулировку вопроса. Я привела только одно значение этого слова и другого не знаю. Это у вас такая странная логика или такой своеобразный юмор?